# Equivalent resistance problem on cascode mirror circuit

Tags: resistance, cascode, mirror

I'm trying to analyze the cascode mirror, specifically its sensitivity to V<sub>CC</sub> variations.

[image]
[image]

Before facing with complicated calculations with the equivalent circuit, the tutorial (I'm following)  advices to find the equivalent of the circuit block on the right of point **A**, giving only the final result of R<sub>eq</sub> :

$$R_{eq} = \frac{v_{A}}{i_{B}} = \frac{2(1+\beta)}{g_{m}}$$

but without explaining the line of reasoning used to find it, with the only exception to consider equal the transconductances of **Q<sub>1</sub>** and **Q<sub>3</sub>**.

By using different approaches, I tried different times to find the same result for the equivalent resistance, but I was not able to find it, and to find an expression for the voltage on point **B**, too.

At this point, I guess that the circuit block on the right of point **A** cannot be solved, and that the tutorial is wrong, unless I'm missing something important...

Could some of you help me to find a line of reasoning in order to find the above expression for R<sub>eq</sub>?

Comment: So you want to find the equivalent resistance seen from Q1 base into the BJT? Because Req seen at point A (between point A and GND) is equal to   1/gm2 + 1/gm4. Due to the fact that r_pi is (beta +1) times large than 1/gm, thus we can ignore r_pi influence.

Comment: @G36 - Could you please detail where the resistances  1/gm2 and 1/gm4 can be found on the equivalent circuit, in order to be able to compare them to r_pi?

Comment: Q2 and Q4 work as diode-connected BJT's. This is why you have 1/gm2 and 1/gm4 on the equivalent diagram. https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkMTY.png

Comment: @G36 - I see. But as explained in my post, I'm looking for finding the Req looking from A to the right side, where there are no 1/gm2 and no 1/gm4...

Comment: But I've already shown you (in my answer) how to find the Req.

Comment: @G36 - Please see my comments about your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, we can assume that:

$$V_{\pi3} \approx \frac{v_A}{2}$$

Do you know why we can do that?

So, we know the \$Q_1\$ emitter current value:

$$i_E \approx g_{m3}\frac{v_A}{2}$$

And \$Q1\$ base current will be equal to:

$$i_B = \frac{i_E}{\beta +1} = \frac{g_{m3}\frac{v_A}{2}}{\beta +1} = \frac{g_{m3} v_A}{2(\beta+1)} = v_A \frac{g_{m3}}{2(\beta+1)} $$

$$\frac{i_B}{v_A} = \frac{g_{m3}}{2(\beta+1)}$$

Therefore:

$$R_{eq} = \frac{v_{A}}{i_{B}} = \frac{v_A}{\frac{g_{m3} v_A}{2(\beta+1)}} = \frac{2 (\beta +1)}{g_{m3}}$$

And this is the end.

Comment: I suppose that your first assumption is valid for a DC regime, but not for small signals...otherwise, I do not know where it comes from.

Comment: Why do you think that V_pi3 = VA/2 does not hold in the small-signal analysis?

Comment: From the complete circuit I can see that, approximatively, the Q1 base voltage (point A) is 2 times that of Q3 base, but the same relation is not so evident from the incremental circuit. On the other hand, I do not think that what is valid for DC is also valid for small signals.

Comment: But in this circuit Ic2 ≈ Ic4 which means that gm2 ≈ gm2 and V_pi3 = Va/2.

Comment: I see it now, even though this is only valid if r_pi3 >> 1/gm4, does it?

Comment: Yes, but r_pi = beta/gm and this means that r_pi is beta times larger than 1/gm. This is why we can ignore r_pi in this case. Because usually, the transistor beta is much large than 10.

Comment: I knew your above notes above. Anyway, thanks a lot; your support was very helpful.

Comment: And I hope that you see that this circular is very sensitive to Vdd change.

Comment: I'm not so convinced about the high sensitivity, considering that it should be equall to (delta Iout)/(delta Vcc)=1/RA. Anyway, it's surely always better than that of Wilson mirror (=2/RA)...

Comment: If you increase the Vcc by 1% the output current will also increase by 1% or more. Thus, the sensitive factor is close to 1 or slightly large than one.